# Confused between Romans 2:12 vs John 14:6

Tags: john, contradiction, romans, soteriology

It appears to be a contradiction to me. In Roman 2:12 Paul states that there is a way to salvation without Jesus if you obey your conscience and have never heard of Jesus. Of course in John 14:6 Jesus states that there is no salvation except through Him. Thanks.

Comment: Good question, but I wouldn't say that John 14:6 says that there is no salvation outside of Jesus. I believe it means that, among other things, but it's arguable. I would rephrase your question to something similar to this: "Does Romans 2:12 say that one can be saved by works if one remains obedient to his conscience?"

Answer (score 2):

Paul is actually making the exact same point as John 14:6, he just takes a while to get there.  If you look at the first part of Romans, Paul is building a case towards that is well summarized by Romans 3:23: "for all have sinned and fall short of the glory of God".

He starts by breaking the world into two groups: Those with the law and those without the law.  Those who have the law fall short of the law's standard and are therefore guilty.  Those without the law fall short of their own standards and are therefore guilty.

The next few verses (especially Romans 2:14,15) Clarify this:

"(Indeed, when Gentiles, who do not have the law, do by nature things required by the law, they are a law for themselves, even though they do not have the law. They show that the requirements of the law are written on their hearts, their consciences also bearing witness, and their thoughts sometimes accusing them and at other times even defending them.)"  (Romans 2:14,15 NIV)

The point he comes to later is that salvation does not come through the law, but through Christ.

Answer (score 0):

I see no contradiction in Romans 2:12.

> For as many as have sinned without law shall also perish without
>   law: and as many as have sinned in the law shall be judged by the law;

*King James Version*

If you do not know the law, you will die not knowing the law.  If you try to follow the letter of the law, the best that you can, you will be judged by the letter of the law; because you are not sinless you will be judged guilty by the letter of the law.  The term *perish* here is usually interpreted as eternal damnation or spending eternity in hell, or eternal separation from God.

Other scriptures are necessary to bridge the gap between the two scriptures you are comparing.  But essentially it comes down to The Sacrifice of Jesus Christ on The Cross, He essentially pays for our sins so that God, The Father, can give us Grace even though we are sinners and forgive us those sins; in this way Jesus Christ is the only way to a relationship with The Father.

Answer (score 0):

> Romans 2:12
>
> > *For as many as did sin without law shall also perish without law; and as many as did sin in the law shall be judged by the law*
>
> John 14:6
>
> > *Jesus saith to him, "I am the way, and the truth, and the life; no one cometh to the Father, except by Me."*

---

To be precise, neither of these verses literally use the words "save" (σῴζω) or "salvation" (σωτηρία).

John 14:6 cannot, I think, be considered in isolation from the rest of the Gospel, perhaps most importantly Matthew 25:31-46 (the account of the Final Judgment).  In this account, *all the nations* (πάντα τὰ ἔθνη) are gathered - without regard to their beliefs.  Many, it will be noted, *inherit the kingdom*, even though they themselves confessed that they did not know him (*Lord, when did we see You?*).

So while John 14:6 is sometimes interpreted negatively, emphasizing Jesus as *the* [only] *Way* - i.e. "you won't get to the Father unless I'm the one who brings you" - I think perhaps a more helpful interpretation is one that sees Christ as the source (in fact, the embodiment) of truth.  According to this understanding, anyone who is following what is true is, in fact, following Jesus.  This is not the same as saying that there are multiple paths to the Father; it is saying that it is possible to be on the path without recognizing it (as was the case in Matthew 25:31-46).  By the same token, it is possible to be on the completely wrong path thinking one is not:  *Why do you call me, Lord, Lord*, Jesus asks, *and not do the things that I say?* (Luke 6:46)

---

Romans 2:12 fits into the overall Gospel theme of Luke 12:48:

> > *But he who knew not, and did things worthy of blows, shall be beaten a little. And everyone to whom much was given, much shall be required of him; and to whom much was committed, the more they will ask of him.*

The verse speaks of judgment, not salvation, and of the standards by which Gentiles (those who are ἀνόμως - lit. "without law") will be judged as opposed to those by which Jews will be judged (διὰ νόμου - lit. "through law").  Paul explains in the verses (14-15) that follow what he has in mind here:

> > *For whenever the Gentiles, who have not the law, do by nature the things of the law, these, who have not the law, are a law unto themselves, who show the work of the law written in their hearts, their conscience bearing witness, and their thoughts one with another accusing or also excusing*

The Byzantine commentator John Chrysostom (c 349-407) explained Romans 2:12:

> For here, as I said before, he shows not only the equality of the Jew and the Gentile, but that the Jew was even much burdened by the gift of the Law. For the Gentile is judged without law. But this “without law” [ἀνόμως] here expresses not the worse plight but the easier, that is, he has not the Law to accuse him. For “without law” (that is, without the condemnation arising from it), is he condemned solely from the reasonings of nature, but the Jew, “in the Law,” that is, with nature and the Law too to accuse him. For the greater the attention he enjoyed, the greater the punishment he will suffer. See how much greater is the necessity which he lays upon the Jews of a speedy recourse to grace! For in that they said, they needed not grace, being justified by the Law, he shows that they need it more than the Gentiles, considering they are liable to be punished more.

In this understanding, coupled with what I think is the proper understanding of John 14:6 in context, I don't believe there is any contradiction.

Answer (score -1):

But about those converted from non-Israelite nations that having trusted in the good news, we (Apostles and Elders in Jerusalem) wrote a letter having judged that none of these things (of the law), they should be saving (They should not observe), if not, they should they are saving as much as possible from what is sacrificed to idols, blood, strangled and sexual immorality.  Acts 21:25

**Reconfirmation of the Jerusalem Synod in Acts 15.**

In practical terms, the Christian people called Gentile, not Judaized, which is outside the country Israel, exclusively to an obligation to keep the biblical laws and their Jewish understandings relating to sacrificed to idols, the laws on blood, the laws on strangled and laws regarding sexual immorality that are not unlawful marital relations.

**Paul exercised his jewish citizenship in Jerusalem**. Acts 21:17.

*take them and purify yourself along with them and pay their expenses, so that they may have their heads shaved. Then everyone will know there is nothing in what they have been told about you, but that you yourself live in conformity with the law*. (At 21:24 [NET])

**In Romans 2, the lawless, are the Gentiles converts who were not circumcised.**

Comment: it is not clear how this answers the question.  Your final statement only mentions the original scripture that the original post is asking about, you haven't even mentioned John 14:6

Answer (score -1):

Neil Elliott explains, in ' Blasphemed Among the Nations: Pursuing an Anti-Imperial "Intertextuality" in Romans', *[As It Is Written](https://books.google.com.au/books/about/As_it_is_Written.html?id=FwxqQacv9b4C&redir_esc=y)* (Edited by Porter and Stanley), pages 226-9, that Romans chapters 2 and 3 consist of a stylised conversation with a Judean as a rhetorical device aimed at his non-Judean audience. He says that verses 2:12-13 are part of this diatribe against the imaginary Jew, to whom he is saying that if they sin in ways not proscribed by the Old Testament law, they will be punished outside the Old Testament law, but if the sin in ways proscribed by the Old Testament law, then it is the Old Testament law that will decide their punishment. Here, Paul is not offering salvation, but explaining that those who sin outside the law can expect to be punished.

John 14:6 portrays Jesus as saying that salvation comes only through him. This is not something that Paul would disagree with. Romans 5:9 says as much:

> [Romans 5:9](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Romans-Chapter-5/#9): Much more then, being now justified by his blood, we shall be saved from wrath through him.